# PHP Copy xml nodes from one doc to another

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

First of all, I need to Find a parent node by a specific child node value in an xml doc; Then copy some specific children nodes from the parent node to another xml doc.

For instance:

```
DESTINATION FILE: ('destination.xml') 
<item>
    <offerStartDate>2012-15-02</offerStartDate>
    <offerEndDate>2012-19-02</offerEndDate>
    <title>Item Title</title> 
    <rrp>14.99</rrp>
    <offerPrice>9.99</offerPrice>
</item>
```

and

```
SOURCE FILE: ('source.xml') 
<items> 
    <item> 
         <title>Item A</title> 
         <description>This is the description for Item A</description> 
         <id>1003</id>
         <price>
             <rrp>10.00</rrp>
             <offerPrice>4.99</offerPrice>
         </price>
         <offer>
             <deal>
                 <isLive>0</isLive>
             </deal>
         </offer>
    </item>
    <item> 
         <title>Item B</title> 
         <description>This is the description for Item B</description> 
         <id>1003</id>
         <price>
             <rrp>14.99</rrp>
             <offerPrice>9.99</offerPrice>
         </price>
         <offer>
             <deal>
                 <isLive>1</isLive>
             </deal>
         </offer>
    </item> 
    <item> 
         <title>Item C</title> 
         <description>This is the description for Item C</description> 
         <id>1003</id>
         <price>
             <rrp>9.99</rrp>
             <offerPrice>5.99</offerPrice>
         </price>
         <offer>
             <deal>
                 <isLive>0</isLive>
             </deal>
         </offer>
    </item>
```

I want to find the parent node `<item>` that has it's child node `<isLive>` value set to "1". Then copy other children nodes of the parent node to the destination xml.

e.g. If parent node `<item>` has its child node `<isLive>` set to 1. Copy `<title>`, `<rrp>` and `<offerPrice>` nodes and their values and add them to the destination file as children nodes as shown above.

Pardon my technical lingo if I have not used them correctly.

Many thanks for the help guys!

Comment: I assume your destination.xml has an items root node, too?

Comment: Yes it does '<item> </item>'. Working on it now thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With SimpleXml ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IWlTIj)):

```
$dItems = simplexml_load_file('destination.xml');
$sItems = simplexml_load_file('source.xml');
foreach ($sItems->xpath('/items/item[offer/deal/isLive=1]') as $item) {
    $newItem = $dItems->addChild('item');
    $newItem->addChild('title', $item->title);
    $newItem->addChild('rrp', $item->price->rrp);
    $newItem->addChild('offerprice', $item->price->offerPrice);
}
echo $dItems->saveXML();
```

With DOM ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GDNfqc)):

```
$destination = new DOMDocument;
$destination->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$destination->load('destination.xml');
$source = new DOMDocument;
$source->load('source.xml');
$xp = new DOMXPath($source);
foreach ($xp->query('/items/item[offer/deal/isLive=1]') as $item)
{
    $newItem = $destination->documentElement->appendChild(
        $destination->createElement('item')
    );
    foreach (array('title', 'rrp', 'offerPrice') as $elementName) {
        $newItem->appendChild(
            $destination->importNode(
                $item->getElementsByTagName($elementName)->item(0),
                true
            )
        );
    }
}
$destination->formatOutput = true;
echo $destination->saveXml();
```

Comment: They both print the new data on the php files but neither saves to the destination xml. Any ideas pls?

Comment: @echez I leave that final bit up to you to figure out from their respective documentation in PHP manual ;)

Comment: @echez if my answer solves your problem I'd be happy if you would accept it by ticking the green check mark next to the voting controls on the left. thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for your help @Gordon. I did sort out the save bit with 'echo $destination->saveXml('destination.xml');' And had to change file permission on the server so that I could write to the file.

Comment: What if both documents have different namespaces? I guess with DOM importNode() also fetches the namespace and adds in the node. What if we don't want to copy namespace?